# False react hooks error #321 - Function is not a React Component Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong or It's a false positive. I'm calling `useEffect` and a custom hook in my component. But I'm getting an error in my console saying "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component". Here is my component code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

// ... other imports ...

export default function LiveDefects({ match }) {
  const { params : { machineTag } } = match
  const { fetchLiveUpdates } = liveActionCreators 

  const state = useStoreValues(['liveData'])
  const { liveData = {} } = state
  const { fetchLiveUpdatesAction } = useDispatchableActions([
    {
      action : fetchLiveUpdates,
      name   : 'fetchLiveUpdatesAction'
    },
  ])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLiveUpdatesAction({ machineTag })
  }, [machineTag])


  return (
    <MainContainer>
      <Header>Live Defects</Header>
      <ul className='grid col-12'>
        <li className='col-4'>
          <div className='col-12 padded-l'>
            <div className='col-12 grid card rounded bordered'>
              <div className='grid-middle grid-center col-12'>
                <img src='https://i.imgur.com/ZccahuC.jpg' alt='le bc' />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </MainContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm the version of React and react-dom in your App

Comment: 16.8 both, react and react-dom

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Basically React is not considering this as a React Functional Component for some reason.

Comment: There are a few reason for this warning and it might not mean what it says. Have a look at this React post: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: of course, I've done my research before posting a question at SO. I've checked that post and I don't think I'm missing anything in the component.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a reproducible demo since the above code doesn't help in finding out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the issue. I was using `render` property instead of `component` in routes:

this is my old code:

```
<Route path='/defect-detection/live-data' render={LiveDefects} />
```

I updated it to:

```
<Route path='/defect-detection/live-data' component={LiveDefects} />
```

Now it's working fine. Annoying, but makes sense.